# Оптимизация избыточной базы данных. Какой из способов будет лучше?

Tags: база-данных, оптимизация, sql

Допустим, есть таблица вида:

```
ID (ключ),
Timesamp,
Серийный_номер (varchar),
Категория_параметра (varchar),
Значение_параметра (int)
```

имеется индекс по всему, кроме ID, в том же порядке.

Вариаций `"Категория_параметра"` - очень конечное количество (допустим, 5 штук).
Запросы нужно строить с выборкой значений по серийнику (коих будет массив) в временном интервале, соответственно, для каждого `"Категория_параметра"`.

Записей в таблице оооочень много (несколько десятков миллионов), размер средней выборки может быть небольшой (десяток тысяч), но простейший запрос занимает неприличное время (с десяток минут).

**Сам вопрос: чтобы побороть избыточность, что будет эффективнее:** 
1) объединить ближайшие по времени записи в такие, где все вариации "Категория_параметра" представлены полями, т.е.:

```
ID,
Timesamp,
Серийный_номер (varchar),
Значение_параметра_1 (int),
Значение_параметра_2 (int),
Значение_параметра_3 (int),
...
```

2) Или же вовсе поделить на разные таблицы, где каждой таблице будет соответствовать какая-то "категория_параметра":

```
Таблица Категория_параметра №1
-----------------------------
ID,
Timesamp,
Серийный_номер (varchar),
Значение (int)

Таблица Категория_параметра №2
-----------------------------
ID,
Timesamp,
Серийный_номер (varchar),
Значение (int)

....
```

ЗЫ Целью будет эффективная "сборка" всех параметров воедино в определенных интервалах с группировкой по серийнику, даже если размер таблицы(таблиц) будет расти и дальше. Проблема именно в огромной таблице, из которой нужно выдернуть не так много значений.

Буду рад любым идеям и доводам!
Спасибо!

ЗЫЫ *Конечно, избыточность ID и Timestamp'ов борется только в первом случае. Но мне интересно теоретическое сравнение (или опыт), что эффективнее: уменьшить в несколько раз количество записей или делать серию запросов из нескольких таблиц (в которых будет в несколько раз меньше данных).*

Comment: Попробуйте просто сделать *комбинируемый индекс* по Timestamp,Серийный_номер.

Если длина данных в *Серийный_номер* различается слабо, то можно также заменить varchar на char.

Не совсем понял, есть ли такой индекс у Вас  отдельный индекс по "неселективному" полю *Категория_параметра*? Если есть, то удалите его.

Comment: эффективнее будет избавиться от varchar'ов в индексах, чем мучиться с партициями или допполями. 10к записей - это не больше мегабайта данных (грубая оценка сверху), дело не в объеме, а в количествах и качествах сравнений. составной индекс для такой таблицы будет сравним с самой таблицей, потому и эффективность его никакая => минуты, десятки минут.

Comment: @avp
Комбинируемый индекс - это индекс по нескольким полям? (только такое определение нашел, на SO). Неплохо дало результат на том этапе, где мне было необходимо собрать массив уникальных серийников. В остальном - глухо. VARCHAR на CHAR заменить нет возможности, ибо серийники разной длины и состава. Индекса два: кластерный (по-умолчанию, по ID записи в таблице) и некластерный по всему, кроме ID, т.к. вся эта информация нужна, иначе, исключив неселективные поля из индекса, но оставив их в операторе `SELECT` , база использует кластерный индекс - бежит подряд по таблице.

Comment: @Free_ze, запрос покАжите? ваши рассуждения не верны.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov

Он простой, примерно такой:

    SELECT 
            [SerialNumber],
            [Timestamp],
            [Category],
            [Value]
    FROM 
            [Table]
    WHERE        
            [Timestamp] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

    ORDER BY 
            [SerialNumber],
            [Timestamp] DESC

Comment: @Free_ze, очевидно, что для эффективности такого запроса нужен *отдельный индекс* по `Timestamp`.

Comment: @Free_ze, в вопросе у вас о другом запросе говорилось. И @avp правильно советовал и по запросу из вопроса - (Timestamp,Серийный_номер), и по запросу из комментария - (Timestamp). Для разных запросов, как нетрудно догадаться могут быть эффективными разные индексы, первоначально надо смотреть на предикат в WHERE. А составной индекс на все поля кроме ID удалите, в нем смысла нет - он большой, он тормозит вставки, по нему выборок у вас скорее всего не будет никогда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понятно причем тут избыточность данных...

Речь, если я верно все понял, идет об оптимизации запросов типа:

```
SELECT         
     [SerialNumber],
     [Timestamp],        
     [Category],        
     [Value]
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Timestamp] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
ORDER BY [SerialNumber], [Timestamp] DESC
```

Ну дык выкиньте `EXPLAIN` (для MySQL) или `SHOWPLAN` (для SQL Server) или `EXPLAIN PLAN` (для Oracle) и изучите узкое место.

Узкое место очевидно или в отработке условия `WHERE` (борется индексацией `Timestamp`) или в сортировке (борется индексацией `SerialNumber/Timestamp`)